# how do I remove git tracking from my desktop in the terminal?

Tags: git, terminal, zsh

I don't have a repo actively setup on my desktop yet I get the git prompt when I head to 'cd Desktop' - how would I remove this? I'm on a mac using zsh and iterm2.

[the label I get when in cd Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjjEB.png)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `.git` directory in Desktop or one of its parents?

Comment: I certainly must have created one by accident! brand new to git and regular terminal use here sorry. I've deleted it with the command given below :)

Answer (score 1):

*Probably* you have an existing **git** repository in there.

Just remove the `.git` directory, e.g. `rm -rf .git`

Comment: thankyou, is that the entire command I'd type inside the Desktop folder? [very new to this, apologies]